# Where to post my Q which is on hold in this site?

Tags: support

I had posted yesterday this question

- [Whether Internet speed be same in tablet computer as in mobile phone?](https://superuser.com/questions/717634/)

It's too good to see one answer I received but unfortunately it's put on hold. Please assist me where I can post this question. I'm eager to get my doubt in the question cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is on hold because it is off-topic. What *exactly* is the question?

> "This piece of hardware is slower than this other piece of hardware,
>   how can I get a new piece of hardware that matches the first?"

That is off-topic. A more pertinent question might be:

> "What's the different in hardware architectures that would produce
>   *seemingly improved* results on X device over Y device?"

Then you can use this information to make an informed decision in the selection of future devices.

Answer (score 0):

Probably fits the bill on [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/) since you're looking at Android tablets.